# How to use helm to search a buffer?

Tags: helm, search, grep, ag, find

I would like to use the helm machinery to search "live" a buffer's lines.

Is this possible? If not how would I go about figuring out how to implement this?

Comment: What live buffer? Do you mean open buffer? If yes can you look for `helm-multi-swoop-all` function.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed.

Comment: You can also use the `helm-occur` command.